# Display data after choose product name using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to use ajax output data from database I pass data product_name and product weight  How can i display product weight out of

Now my Output

```
  <select>category</select> //after select category It will display product name
   <select>productname</select> //after select productname How can i display my product weight outof select tag
```

i want to display `<span>product_weight</span>` after I choose product_name

Here is my AJAX call . i try to console my data i get product_weight in my data already.

```
  var op=" ";
                $.ajax({
                    type:'get',
                    url:'{!!URL::to('findProductName')!!}',
                    data:{'id':cat_id},
                    success:function(data){
                        // console.log('success');
                        console.log(data);
                        // console.log(data.length);
                        op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>chose product</option>';

                        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                            op+='<option value="'+data[i].id_p+'" name="id_p">'+data[i].product_name+data[i].product_weight+'</option>';
                        }


                        div.find('.productname').html(" ");
                        div.find('.productname').append(op);

                         // console.log(data.length);

                       },
                       error:function(){

                       }
                     });
```

here is my html

```
<select style="width:50%;" class="productcategory" id="prod_cat_id"  name="id_c[]">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">category</option>
    @foreach($category as $c)
    <option value="{{$c->id_c}}" name="id_c" id="id_c">{{$c->category_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<select style="width:48%;" class="productname" name="id_p[]">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true"> productname</option>
</select>
```

here is my append jeavescript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add-form').click(function() {
        i++;
        $('#add-me').append(


            '<tbody id="row'+i+'"><tr>'+

            '<td class="col-md-7">'+
            '<select style="width:50%;" class="productcategory" id="prod_cat_id"  name="id_c['+ i +']"><option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">category</option>@foreach($category as $c)<option value="{{$c->id_c}}" name="id_c[]" id="id_c[]">{{$c->category_name}}</option>@endforeach</select><select style="width:48%;" class="productname" name="id_p['+ i +']"><option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true"> product name</option></select>'
            +'</td>'
            +'<td class="col-md-1">'
            +'<div id="target_div_where_to_display_weight['+i+']" name="target_div_where_to_display_weight['+i+']">'
            +'</div>'
            +'<td class="col-md-1">'
            +'<input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity_box[]" class="form-control"/>'
            +'</td>'
            +'<td class="col-md-1">'
            +'<input id="unit_price" type="text" name="unit_price[]" class="form-control"/>'
            +'</td>'
            +'<td class="col-md-1">'
            +'<input id="price" type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control"/>'
            +'</td>'

            +'<td class="col-md-2">'
            +'<button id="'+i+'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delegated-btn">Delete</button>'
            +'</td>'
            +'</tr></tbody>'
            );

        $('button.btn.btn-danger').click(function() {
            var whichtr = $(this).closest("tr");
            whichtr.remove(); 
        });

    });
});

</script>
```

**here is my output look like
update**
[image]

Comment: what does this code do now?

Comment: this code select product_name product_weight from database using  findProductName  function

Comment: so this code works with no bugs? you want to add some functionality to it?

Comment: yes sir i add my html @JaromandaX it all  i just want to my product_weight display to my html I alredy get data in my function but i dnt know how to display it

Comment: Just now i select my category it will display productname correctly but after i choose product name i want to display product weight i dnt know how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store product_weight in a new tag attribute inside each option tag, like "data-weight". In order to display the corresponding weight you would just need to do this:

```
    $("select.productname").on("change",function(){
        var weight = $(this).find(":selected").data("weight"); // .attr("data-weight");
        var span = "<span>"+weight+"</span>";
        $("#target_div_where_to_display_weight").html(span);
    });
```

**UPDATE**
In your ajax request replace:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    op+='<option value="'+data[i].id_p+'" name="id_p">'+data[i].product_name+data[i].product_weight+'</option>';
}
```

by

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    op+='<option value="'+data[i].id_p+'" name="id_p" data-product_weight="'+data[i].product_weight+'">'+data[i].product_name+data[i].product_weight+'</option>';
}
```

and in the code i wrote before replace the first instruction by:

```
var weight = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_weight"); // or .attr("data-product_weight");
```

**UPDATE 2**
If you want to append to a div the weight of each product you choose, the should look like this:
First, change your "#target_div_where_to_display_weight" div by a "<div id='weights_wrapper'></div>", then change the first function (on change) by:

```
<pre>$("select.productname").on("change",function(){
    var prod = $(this).find(":selected"); // .attr("data-weight");
    var weight = prod.data("product_weight");
    var id_p = prod.val();
    var added_content = "";
    var content = "&#60;div class='weight' data-ip_p='"+id_p+"'>&#60;span>"+weight+"&#60;/span>"+added_content+"&#60;/div>";
    $("#weights_wrapper").append(content);
});</pre>
```

In this way you can add anchor tags to manage every weight's block. For example, if you want to delete a weight after adding it, you could set added_content = '<a href="#" class="close_weight"></a>'; and then createthe following function:

```
<pre>$("#weights_wrapper").on("click",".close_weight",function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});</pre>
```

Comment: {product_name: "water", id_p: 11, product_weight: "1"} here in my console and i already change my .data("weight") to .data("product_weight")

Comment: thank you. It's work  = =" i shd lern more about javascript thank a lot

Comment: I use dynamic add I try to  '<div id="target_div_where_to_display_weight['+i+']">'  is thier anyway to display in array loop sir , in my productname class i store name="id_p[]" in an arrays

Comment: @user8663822 What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: i mean how can to use with dynamic addd i already update my code i used append () in my code i try to target_div_where_to_display_weight [i]

Comment: i try to  $("#target_div_where_to_display_weight").html(span);
 $("#target_div_where_to_display_weight1").html(span);
 $("#target_div_where_to_display_weigh2t").html(span);

Comment: You can try this: $("#target_div_where_to_display_weight"+$(this).find(":selected").val()).html(span); ...... This will work if your number of "target" is the same than the product id (id_p)

Comment: I think it's almost work haha  working i updated my last output  and If you don't mind i put it into guthub https://github.com/akirawinz/stock-proj thank you